# Vertica NEXTVAL() function - how to invoke it on a record level by condition?

Tags: sequence, vertica

I'm using Vertica Analytic Database v9.2.1-20,

and trying to get next sequence value by condition on a record level, with **NEXTVAL()** function.

here is the example

```
CREATE SEQUENCE v_seq START 1;

CREATE TABLE test_seq (id INT, flag int);
INSERT INTO test_seq VALUES (1, 0);
INSERT INTO test_seq VALUES (2, 1);
INSERT INTO test_seq VALUES (3, 1);
INSERT INTO test_seq VALUES (4, 0);
INSERT INTO test_seq VALUES (5, 0);
INSERT INTO test_seq VALUES (6, 1);
INSERT INTO test_seq VALUES (7, 1);

SELECT  id,
        flag,
        CASE 
           WHEN flag = 0 THEN NEXTVAL('v_seq') 
           ELSE CURRVAL('v_seq') 
        END as group_id
  FROM test_seq 
ORDER BY ID;
```

The expected results :

```
id  flag    group_id
1   0       1
2   1       1
3   1       1
4   0       2
5   0       3
6   1       3
7   1       3
```

The actual results :

```
id  flag    group_id
1   0       1
2   1       2
3   1       3
4   0       4
5   0       5
6   1       6
7   1       7
```

It looks like the NEXTVAL() function is being invoked regardless WHEN condition.

Is there any way to invoke it by condition ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Several tests of mine - in Vertica 10 that is - caused the same behaviour you report above.

There is no way to get it to do what you want, as it seems.

As said elsewhere, you could use `CONDITIONAL_TRUE_EVENT(flag=0) OVER(ORDER BY id)` to obtain your desired result.

There is the risk of being slow, as you have no PARTITION BY in your OLAP window specification, therefore running single-threaded, in the case of a big table.

But a big table will be segmented.

In a segmented table, with `seq.nextval`, each portion/segment of the table will start the sequence you use at a different multiple of, by default, 250,000. In node 1, the sequence starts at 1, in node 2, the sequence starts at 250,000, in node 3 at 500,000, etc. If the table is not segmented, the sequence generator will cause a single-threaded process, too, thus penalising your performance. So you are somehow between a rock and a hard place....

If the table is segmented, you could parallelise the CONDITIONAL_TRUE_EVENT() call, by using the base table's segmentation criterion as the PARTITION BY criterion in the OLAP function call.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar problem.  The way vertica handles sequences for multiple nodes is what causes the core problem (even with just one node).  Since the system has to perform a catalog lock (across all nodes in the cluster), sequences are allocated in large blocks.  You can change the block size but that's not particularly helpful.

To solve the problem, mainly getting a controlled quantity of sequenced values we cached them and allocated them from Java memory.  Once the database allocates them, they will not be re-allocated.  This will get you closer to what you are trying to achieve but takes more work.